# Setup window application server at home

Tags: c#, windows, websocket, signalr, server

I have a domain name from Godady
I have a PC and Windows Server 2010R2 (or other version) installed
I have a NBN with 100mbps internet access and a configurable router

I want to host a windows C# server application on that PC, it that possible to do that?

at this stage i dont care for speed, and i just want to be able to access my server application through a url(an IP or domain) remotely by an client application (possible using websocket or signalR), there is no requirement to use a database.

I dont use AWS or azure because i dont have a creadit card( sad...).

I am open for suggestion and i need a direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it is possible to setup a application server at home.
Considering you have a Godaddy domain, a PC and a windows server license
and you have already setup your IIS and hosted the web application on your PC, 
all you'll need is a Static IP Address from your Internet Service Provider(ISP) which can be access from anywhere on the internet.
Once you have a static IP in your Godaddy CPanel add/edit a "A record" which will point to your home PC.
How to add the A Record can be found in the link below

https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names

You may then use the domain name registered with godaddy to access your web application hosted on your home PC

Comment: thanks, i will try that, one follow up question, will a dynamic IP work? i can update the change if my IP changes

Comment: dynamic IP will work but you'll need to change the A Record as often as your IP change.